# How to get (osm) way by node using osmosis

Tags: nodes, openstreetmap

How can I retrieve the way (id, or this way tag and its nodes) when the node (x,y) is on this way?

Something inefficient that will works (sometimes...) just for example, is to ask google what the name of the way of this node (somehow), and after that using osmosis to filter by tag with this road name.

But I think there is better way to do that.

Note: I don't care if the osmosis is worked on xml file or db. both are fine for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't clear, what do you want to do, but if you search the nearest node or edge for a given GPS coordinate, as I know Osmosis is not the good choice for you, because it is a data conversion tool.

You should export your data file to a PostgreSQL+PostGIS Database (for example with Osmosis) and then you will be able to create queries with SQL.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know that osmosis can't do that.
Anyway, my map is on postgres-db. Now I want to find the address of given GPS coordinate (actually I just want the way's Id).